# trouble installing ros on Ubuntu

Tags: rosinstall, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get ros set up on my Linux Machine and I've been following this tutorial

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

When I get to step 1.4 Under install where I install ROS and I go with the Desktop-Full Install which is recommended I get the following error after entering the command: sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Either way I can't install it and I'm not sure why. How do I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200414/trouble-installing-ros-on-ubuntu/) by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-01-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-05**:
@tfoote FYI

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-05**:
@aadkinz It looks like apt-get is in a bad state, you can try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to resolve the issue, but that's really a shot in the dark.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-05**:
What platform/arch are you on?

**Comment by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on 2015-01-05**:
Ubuntu 14.04

**Comment by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on 2015-01-05**:
I also tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and that didn't help

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-05**:
What is your hardware?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-01-06**:
Do you have the universe and multiverse repositories enabled?

**Comment by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on 2015-01-06**:
This is my laptop
I'm using a Toshiba Satellite S55B266

and ahendrix. I believe I do I'm not quite sure

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-06**:
To debug this issue. Please try to install the dependencies which are erroring. At some level there's a conflict, unfortunately apt won't tell you the error from below. So you'll need to recursively try each of the dependencies until you find the one which gives a useful error.

**Comment by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on 2015-01-06**:
I just put Linux on my computer for ROS does that mean that I do

```
apt-cache search ros-indigo
```

and manually install each package in that list until I find the error?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-06**:
No, follow the errors when you ask to install. desktop-full is erroring on simulators, so try installing simulators. If something underneath errors. Try installing each one that errors, and dig down that way.

**Comment by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on 2015-01-06**:
Ok I did that and that did the trick.

Thanks!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-06**:
What was the problem?

**Comment by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on 2015-01-06**:
I'm not sure exactly. All I did was `sudo apt-get install` and each time I was get the error that I got for the simulator package until I got to the dependency `libsdformat1` after I did `sudo apt-get install libsdformat1` all the other dependencies starting working correctly.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-06**:
If you still have the output of your install of libsdformat1 I expect you'll see that it uninstalled a conflicting package when it installed that. It would be great to know what that package was for others to reference in the future.

**Comment by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on 2015-01-06**:
I never closed my terminal, but I don't see it there anymore. Is it saved to any kind of log I can pull up? Sorry if I seem like I don't know what I'm talking about, but I'm new to Linux. and it's quite a bit too. I'm not sure it would all fit here.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-06**:
To add more information you can edit your question.  You might be able to find something in the logs. LIke /var/log/dpkg.log   You can also enable a longer scroll history on your terminal to get keep more history. That's very useful in cases like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem of unmet dependencies. Install aptitude and run this command

```
sudo aptitude install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

When everything is done, do check apt state by running

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

It should return the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ros-indigo-desktop-full is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

I faced this problem twice on different machines and this solved it both times. I feel apt is not well equipped to handle dependencies and aptitude does it better.

---

Originally posted by [sjsingh](https://answers.ros.org/users/29150/sjsingh/) with karma: 31 on 2017-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0